# Displaying GRIB file values with netCDF

Tags: java, netcdf, grib

I am trying to display data contained in GRIB file using netCDF library, GRIB file is opened correctly because i can access variables in `List<Variables> vars` and display each one of the values but when I try to define `Array Convective_Available_Potential_Energy_surface = CAPE.read();`  i get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` at that line.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        NetcdfFile ncf = NetcdfFile.open("C:\\Users\\TTT\\Desktop\\test.grb"); //loading grib file
        out.println("Variable names are:");
        List<Variable> vars = ncf.getVariables();    //listing variables
       for (Variable var : vars) {
           out.println(var.getName());
        }

        Variable CAPE = ncf.findVariable("Convective_Available_Potential_Energy_surface");

        Array Convective_Available_Potential_Energy_surface = CAPE.read();

        while(Convective_Available_Potential_Energy_surface.hasNext())
            System.out.printf("%f,", Convective_Available_Potential_Energy_surface.nextDouble() );


        ncf.close();
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but you might find it easiest to convert the grib file to netcdf using cdo and read that? cdo -f nc copy in.grb out.nc